# Screenshot not storing to a file in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, screenshot

I have been using *using* ubuntu's native ***snipping tool***, which uses `gnome-screenshot`, but now I have observed that it is not saving pictures at all in picture directory when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>. It is giving that flash though. Screen shot using <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> is working fine. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Normal screen shot is working fine: please explain what "normal screenshot"  is for you. And explain more clearly and specifically what you attempt that does not result in what you expect. Can't you stick with the "normal screen shot"  if that works fine?

Comment: i mean screen shot using  `prnt_screen` but the snipping tool with `ctrl + alt+ prnt screen` is not storing images , it is giving that flash though @vanadium

Comment: Please edit your question to add this explanation and improve clarity.

Comment: I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 16.04, and also noticed that using Ctrl+Alt+PrtSc no longer automatically opens up a prompt to save the file as an image. Got to love it when an upgrade loses functionality!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, the output of your screenshot is to the clipboard rather than to a file. For example, after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>, a screenshot of your current window will be made and will be stored in the clipboard. You can then paste that image in for example a Writer document.

Thus, leave out the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to have it written to a file.

You can see the different shortcut keys in "Settings" - "Keyboard", "Customize Shortcuts", section "Screenshots".

Comment: God dude , thanks So `Shift + prntscreen` i had to do